# Does the highpoly mesh have to have a clean topology, or the exact subdivided version of the lowpoly for which it will be used as a baking source?

Tags: texturing, baking, topology, retopology

I dyntopo in sculpting a lot and use that Dyntopoed high poly mesh as the baking source for the retopoed lowpoly. I have tested it a few times, never had issues with with the results. But I was wondering if this is a pernicious approach, that there might be unknown drawbacks somewhere in the bushes waiting to bite me in the rear at any given time. I appreciate any educated opinions on this.

Answer (score 3):

No, the high poly doesn't have to have clean topology.

There are a few different ways that we can get good, smooth normals.  One way is to use clean topology.  The other way is to just use so many vertices that interpolation between those vertices doesn't really matter.  (These are continuous-- the more vertices you use, the less you have to care about topo, and the more careful you are with topo, the fewer vertices you can get away with.)

The whole reason for the high->low workflow that has become popular is to enable modelling without having to worry about topo at the same time.  So you use techniques like booleans or dynotopo, and then don't worry about the topo until you actually retopologize your mesh.

That said, a high poly *does* have to have enough vertex density to actually make this work!  If you just do some low poly booleans and then bake smooth shaded normals, you'll be baking in the exact same shading artifacts that you see on the high poly.  In order to get away with poor topo, a high poly needs to actually be high poly.